# Dr. X's assistant or Dr. X assistant?

Tags: politeness

I don't know how to introduce myself in e-mails, am I Dr X's assistant or Dr. X assistant?

Answer (score 7):

Use the possessive form: *Dr. X's assistant*.

You could also turn it around and say it without the possessive: *an assistant to Dr. X*.

Answer (score 2):

You are *Dr Smith's assistant* in almost all cases. If his name ends in s, you may be *Dr Jones' assistant* or *Dr Jones's assistant* depending on the style you and Dr Jones prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Doctor X possesses an assistant (well, he doesn't own *you*, but he owns your services as his assistant, so the possession stands). As such, you use the *'s* to denote said possession:

> I am Dr. X assistant.

The meaning conveyed is *I am the/an assistant working with Dr. X*.  You might say that as well.